# NSDateFormatter issue when date string convert into NSDate object

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE,d MMM YYYY"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
     NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
     dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Sun,2 Nov 2014"];
```

output date from string giving wrong output like 2013-12-21 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: what is the expected output???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me guess, you are doing this to test the output:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
```

instead do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```

This is because `NSLog()` will call `[NSDate description]` to format the date and that won't account for any formatting or time zone you may want.

Comment: you are right but it give me wrong date output for giveing string date.

Comment: parameter for dateFromString: Method is @"Sun,2 Nov 2014" and it give me output Sun,22 Dec 2013

Comment: @VinodJadhav OK try `yyyy` rather than `YYYY`.